# Redirect 1 domain to other base on url ending

Tags: php, regex, redirect

So I think this is really simple yet I am have trouble making it. I want it to be used 2 ways [so its 2 scripts].
*Always redirect url is redirect.com and base.url is base.com [base.com can be swapped to other urls if I need]*

**1. When I typein: redirect.com/?q=search what it actually does is redirects to base.com/q=search**

**2. When I typein browser redirect.com/path-to-some-url what it actually does is goes to base.com/path-to-some-url  - of course theres unlimited paths of urls.**

Could somebody help?
Id prefer pure php file code where I just put base.com and rest happens per url entrance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Put this in the index.php file for redirect.com:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://base.com/q='.$_GET["q"]); 
?>
```